# Pointer to a structure involving mutiple c source files

Tags: c, pointers, structure, typedef

I am a beginner in c programming and please forgive any obvious mistakes that I might make.
My question- I have a header and source file already given to me(shown below)-

header1.h

```
#ifndef .....
#define .....

typedef struct
{
    int a1,b1; //a's=input and b's=ouput
    int a2,b2;
    int a3,b3;
    int a4,b4;
}xx_xx;
int xxcalc(xx_xx *y);
endif;
```

source.c

```
#define "header1.h"
#define <stdio.h>
int xxcalc(xx_xx *y)
{
    y->b1 = 2 * a1;
    y->b2 = 3 * a2 + a1;
    y->b3 = a3 + 7;
    y->b4 = a4 / 3;
    return 1;
}
```

Now i am required to write a main source file and then find the result by computing the expressions using msp430 micro controller. I am using code composer studio for doing this.

main.c

```
#define "header1.h"
#define <stdio.h>
// few lines of code to disable watchdog timer
void main()
{
    int data1[10],r;
    y = &data1;
    y->a1 = 2;
    y->a2 = 3;
    y->a3 = 4;
    y->a4 = 5;
    r = b1 * b2 + b3 + b4;
}
```

Now when I compile this and check the registers none of my inputs are considered and there is garbage value in its place.
what am I doing wrong?
Is my method of entering inputs and accessing the value of the output variables declared in the structure correct?

Comment: Where have you defined your variable `y` that you use in `main`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but `header1.h` appears to have typos in it. Please paste the exact code to save querying whether typos are actually correct.

Comment: ... and shouldn't the `a1` in `xxcalc(xx_xx *y)` be `y->a1`, etc etc.

Comment: "when I compile this" you can't *possibly* have compiled the code fragments, even if they were part of a larger body of code.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to declare a variable of the struct in order to access it's members . Something like this :

```
xx_xx y;
```

Secondly you are trying to assign `y = &data1` where data1 considering your code is an array of 10 integers and y is of type xx_xx . That's wrong in any way i can think of .

Please post more information so i that i can help you . 
Thanks .